# CSS Transition Snap Back

Tags: css

I've seen a few questions similar to mine but no real answers. Is there a way to prevent an snap back to the starting frame once you take your mouse off hovering over the link?

If you un-hover from the element it just snaps back to it's original starting frame rather than smoothly transitioning back

This is what I have got:

```
<style>
        .Homeb {
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border: 5px solid;
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
            
            
        }

        a.home {
            transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        a.home:hover {
            border: 5px solid;
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
            
        }
        
    </style>

<body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="Homeb">
                        <a href="index.html" class="home">text</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
             </nav>
        </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pre-define your `border-width` you should be able to achieve what you're looking for:

```css
.Homeb {
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border: 5px solid;
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
            
            
        }

        a.home {
            transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-width:0; /*pre-defined border-width*/
            border-style:solid; /*added*/
        }

        a.home:hover {
            border-width:5px;
            background-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-color: rgb(167, 0, 0);
            border-radius: 5px;
            
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="Homeb">
                        <a href="index.html" class="home">text</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
             </nav>
        </header>
</body>
```